# One-sided confidence interval for correlation coefficient

Tags: self-study, correlation, confidence-interval

Consider this question,

> Let $(X_1,Y_1),(X_2,Y_2),...,(X_n,Y_n)$ be independent and identically
>   distributed pairs of random variables with $E(X_1) = E(Y_1), Var(X_1)= Var(Y_1) = 1$, and $Cov(X_1,Y_1) = \rho \in (-1,1).$
>
> Given $\alpha \in (0,1)$, obtain a statistic $L_n$ which is a function
>   of $(X_1,Y_1),(X_2,Y_2),...,(X_n,Y_n)$ such that  \begin{align}
> \displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}P(L_n < \rho < 1) = \alpha \end{align}

My concern is that since it is given that $\rho \in (-1,1)$, can I drop the $1$ in the equality to be proven. I mean, will the statistic $L_n$ calculated such that it satisfies
\begin{align}
\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}P(L_n < \rho) = \alpha 
\end{align}
would also satisfy the given equation. And if not, how should I go about this problem?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3202067/finding-l-n-so-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-pl-n-rho1-alpha/.

Comment: I had calculated it the same way once I dropped off the $1$ from the equation. However, I want to ask that can I do that?

Comment: The question asks for a lower confidence bound for the correlation; it is of course bounded above by $1$, whether you mention it or not.